# Comment system with twitter and facebook login. Like pinterest

Tags: facebook, twitter, system, comments, pinterest

I was wondering if you know any comment system that allows you to comment with Twitter or Facebook account similar to the one they use at pinterest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve you can use [facebook comment plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) to get a pinterest type comment box :)

Comment: But i also want twitter users to be able to comment :)

Comment: Steve I guess u r getting confused. pinterest only registers you thru facebook and twitter and stores your details(like pic, name, email) in there db. The comment box here is their own(nothing to do with fb or twitter), where they simply uses your credentials to log u in and make u the session user and ask u to post comments. So just go thru the developers tutorial for both the apps and login thru them built your own coment box or use some exsisting one to post comment :)

Comment: That's true Charsee. I finally realised about it and that's on what i am working right now. Thanks!!